# Inserting into two colums in a temp table with 2 different subqueries

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is it possible to insert data into two colums in a temp table with 2 different subqueries?

I have tried the following

```
CREATE TABLE #Temp (
FromPlanInvtId BIGINT
,ToPlanInvtId BIGINT
)

INSERT INTO #Temp (
FromPlanInvtId 
,ToPlanInvtId
)
VALUES (
(SELECT PlanInvtId FROM PR_PLANINVESTMENTS WHERE PlanId = 65)
,(SELECT PlanInvtId FROM PR_PLANINVESTMENTS WHERE PlanId = 214)
)
```

Here both the subqueries **returns more than one value**

Is there any other way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  Use `insert . . . select`:

```
INSERT INTO #Temp (FromPlanInvtId, ToPlanInvtId)
    SELECT (SELECT PlanInvtId FROM PR_PLANINVESTMENTS WHERE PlanId = 65),
           (SELECT PlanInvtId FROM PR_PLANINVESTMENTS WHERE PlanId = 214);
```

This assumes that each subquery returns at most one row.  Otherwise, you will get an error to the effect that "subquery returns more than one row".

Edit:

If the subqueries return more than one value, then you can get all combinations with:

```
INSERT INTO #Temp (FromPlanInvtId, ToPlanInvtId)
    SELECT t1.PlanInvtId , t2.PlanInvtId 
    FROM (SELECT PlanInvtId FROM PR_PLANINVESTMENTS WHERE PlanId = 65
         ) t1 CROSS JOIN
         (SELECT PlanInvtId FROM PR_PLANINVESTMENTS WHERE PlanId = 214
         ) t2;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Drop table #Temp 
CREATE TABLE #Temp (
FromPlanInvtId BIGINT
,ToPlanInvtId BIGINT
)

INSERT INTO #Temp (
FromPlanInvtId 
,ToPlanInvtId
)
Select

(SELECT PlanInvtId FROM PR_PLANINVESTMENTS WHERE PlanId = 65),
(SELECT PlanInvtId FROM PR_PLANINVESTMENTS WHERE PlanId = 214)
```

Comment: both the subqueries returns more than one value

Comment: it will definitely throws an error so we need to handle this one in where condition..we have multiple records we need to filter the data basing on conditions

Comment: But I can only filter this much.. I need multiple data to be inserted.